# Java 8 Lambda Expression

Tags: java-8

I am new learner for Java 8 lambda . 
I found a statement in a book (**Java 8 for Really Impatient** ),  saying , 
"***It is illegal for a lambda expression to return a value in some branches but not in others. For example, (int x) -> { if (x >= 0) return 1; } is invalid.***"

Can anyone explain this ? Please provide some examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your confusion. You already have an example with an explanation. It's invalid because only one of two branches returns a value.

Comment: No matter if you write a standard method or something like the lambda expression above, the code needs to have some defined outcome. In your example, for a negative input (`x`) the expression is not returning anything - which is not allowed.

Comment: This book should be retitled Java 8 for Really patient. Java 8 is out for 3 years now ;-)

Comment: @C-Otto , Thanks for ur reply . Got it !! . Somehow missed the context

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , Thanks for ur reply .

Answer (score 4):

I don't get it where you don't get it. Will this compile for example?

```
 static int test(int x) {
    if(x >= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
 }
```

Same goes for the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

you have to ensure no matter "if" statement is true or false, there is always a return value or there is always not.

In your case:

illegal: `(int x) -> { if (x >= 0) return 1; }`
legal: `(int x) -> { if (x >= 0) return 1; else return 0;}`

This is because this method below is illegal

```
int lambda (int x){
    if (x >= 0)
        return 1;
}
```